# Can not install Console-setup , dependencies required

Tags: ubuntu-one, syslinux

I had some issues with my Ubuntu 16.04 more specifically Python and it's dependencies, which I tried to fix by installing and removing packages using Synaptic Package Manager.

Without further due, the package manager had started to delete more than it was supposed to.

After this I tried to reboot my computer, I received the message shown in picture:

[image]

Suggestions online said to reinstall console-setup.
This was not successful as it failed to install because of dependencies such as:. 
`console-setup-linux` and `keyboard configuration`

[image]

Comment: Tried to provide a photo from my phone, this did not work.

Comment: Hi tatsu, thank you for your feedback . Let me know if it's ok .

Comment: okay that's better. so captain hindsight phoning in: Synaptic Package Manager is a plague and you should never use it. I don't think even experts bother, by that point they're way to comfortable with the terminal. but apt package management is well set up so to the apt-deb-ppa trinity is your god, please worship it with due dilligence from now on and renounce the false prophet and acursed fallen angel synaptic. to fix your blunder I suggest running `sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f`

Comment: I forgot to add the commands I have already tried. Yours have already been tried out, and I just wonder if I should take a backup (if possible) and restore everything.

Comment: I fixed this problem by manually installing the version of keyboard-configuration it was requiring.  But now it looks like I don't have no GUI no more .

Comment: Any idea how I can get greeter back? Tried to install gnome-session ubuntu-dekstop, but dependencies problems here too....

Comment: well you may have uninstalled the ubuntu desktop entirely (you are on ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10 right? ) : `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-gnome-desktop -y`... well done on the `keyboard-configuration` bit, btw!

Comment: As mentioned : Ubuntu 16.04